# Create sequence consisting of multiple property values

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have an existing collection of objects with two properties of interest. Both properties are of the same type. I want to create a new sequence consisting of the property values. Here's one way (I'm using tuples instead of my custom type for simplicity):

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
    { Tuple.Create("dog", "cat"), Tuple.Create("fish", "frog") };

var result =
    list.SelectMany(x => new[] {x.Item1, x.Item2});

foreach (string item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Results in:

```
dog
cat
fish
frog
```

This gives me the results I want, but is there a better way to accomplish this (in particular, without the need to create arrays or collections)?

**Edit:**

This also works, at the cost of iterating over the collection twice:

```
var result = list.Select(x => x.Item1).Concat(list.Select(x => x.Item2));
```

Comment: What is the "result [you] want"? Having a jagged array? Creating a list of anonymous types?...

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, you could do `var result = new [] { "dog", "cat", "fish", "frog" };`  But if you have to start with the list of tuples, then what you have looks great.

Comment: @jmh_gr - I just edited the question for clarity. I want an `IEnumerable<string>` consisting of `originalListFirstItem.StringProperty1`, `originalListFirstItem.StringProperty2`, `originalListSecondItem.StringProperty1`, `originalListSecondItem.StringProperty2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid creating another collection, you could yield the results instead.

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>
        { Tuple.Create("dog", "cat"), Tuple.Create("fish", "frog") };

        foreach (var element in GetSingleList(list))
        {
            Console.WriteLine (element);
        }
}

// A reusable extension method would be a better approach.
IEnumerable<T> GetSingleList<T>(IEnumerable<Tuple<T,T>> list) {

    foreach (var element in list)
    {
        yield return element.Item1;
        yield return element.Item2;
    }

}
```

Comment: *Very* nice. I'm accepting this as (a) it does not create new arrays/collections and (b) it only iterates over the original collection once. The parameter type could be `IEnumerable<Tuple<T,T>>` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach is fine and I would stick with that. The use of the array nicely gets the job done when using `SelectMany`, and the final result is an `IEnumerable<string>`.

There are some alternate approaches, but I think they're more verbose than your approach.

`Aggregate` approach:

```
var result = list.Aggregate(new List<string>(), (seed, t) =>
{
    seed.Add(t.Item1);
    seed.Add(t.Item2);
    return seed;
});
result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

`ForEach` approach:

```
var result = new List<string>();
list.ForEach(t => { result.Add(t.Item1); result.Add(t.Item2); });
result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

In both cases a new `List<string>` is created.